# What framework is trac based on?

Tags: python, frameworks, trac

I just downloaded this [tracking system](http://trac.edgewall.org/) and curious what framework this great system uses?

Answer (score 9):

Trac does not use any overarching external "framework". You can see its complete list of external dependencies (beyond a Python interpreter itself) in the `setup.py` file from the distribution:

```
    install_requires = [
        'setuptools>=0.6b1',
        'Genshi>=0.6',
    ],
    extras_require = {
        'Babel': ['Babel>=0.9.5'],
        'Pygments': ['Pygments>=0.6'],
        'reST': ['docutils>=0.3'],
        'SilverCity': ['SilverCity>=0.9.4'],
        'Textile': ['textile>=2.0'],
    },
```

If you're particularly interested in the HTTP side of things, take a look at the [source to the `trac.web` module](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/trunk/trac/web).